# Adding group name row to group member output

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to export some group memberships all to one CSV file so I can find users who are not in our domain.  Everything works great, but when all the outputs get appended I can't see what group each entry is in.  Here's what I have now.

```
$Groups = import-csv "C:\users\USER\desktop\secgroupinput2.csv"
foreach($item in $Groups)
{

Get-ADGroupMember -Server "SERVERDC" -Identity $item.directoryname | export-csv "C:\users\USER\desktop\realexport.csv" -Append
}
```

How can I add a row between appends with the group name, likely from the import?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar in the past. Hope this code helps :

```
Function ADGroupMembers
{
$group = get-content C:\Pshell\PM\group.txt 
$i =25

do{
if (get-QADgroup $group[$i] -Empty 0) 
    {write-output ''; Write-Output -inputobject "The $($group[$i]) group members :"; write-output ''; 
 get-QADGroupMember $group[$i] -IncludeAllProperties | Format-Table -AutoSize DisplayName, Type, Office, Company, Department, Title, WhenCreated  | Out-String -Width 4096; 
 write-output ''} 

else {Write-Output -inputobject "*** Member not found in the $($group[$i]) group!"; write-output ''}
$i +=1}
while ($i -ne $group.length)
}

ADGroupMembers | out-File 'c:\Pshell\PM\groupmemberdetails.txt'
```